Question on Lagrange series inversion proof
I am stuck in understanding a passage of a proof I have found for Lagrange series inversion formula.
The theorem is proven in the following form:

Consider the equation $x=y+\epsilon f(x)$ where $f$ is analytic, $f(0)=0$ and $|\epsilon f'(x)|<1$, where we seek a solution $x=X(y,\epsilon)$ in the form of the following power series $$X(y,\epsilon)=y+\epsilon X_1(y,\epsilon)+\epsilon^2 X_2(y,\epsilon)+...$$
The solution $x=X(y,\epsilon)$ is given by the series of functions (if it converges)
$$X(y,\epsilon)=y+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\epsilon^nX_n(y)$$
where $$X_n(y)=\frac{1}{n!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dy^{n-1}}[((f(y))^n]$$
The convention is that $\frac{d^{0}}{dy^{0}}f(y)=f(y)$. In addition, if $g$ is an analytic function such that $g(0)=0$, then
$$g(X)=g(y)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\epsilon^nG_n(y)$$
where $$G_n(y)=\frac{1}{n!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dy^{n-1}}[((f(y))^ng'(y)]$$

The proof goes as following:

As $|\epsilon f'(x)|$ the implicit function theorem guarantees the existence of a unique solution $x=X(y,\epsilon)$ in a neighborhood of $x=y$.
By differentiating $x=y+\epsilon f(x)$ we get
$$dX=dy+\epsilon f'(X)dX+f(X)d\epsilon$$ from which it follows that
$$\frac{\partial X}{\partial\epsilon}=\frac{f(X)}{1-\epsilon f'(X)}=f(X)\frac{\partial X}{\partial y}$$
Let $F$ and $G$ be any two regular functions. From the previous formula it follows that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\epsilon}F(X(y,\epsilon))=f(X(y,\epsilon))\frac{\partial}{\partial y}F(X(y,\epsilon))$$
and hence
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\epsilon}\left[F(X(y,\epsilon))\frac{\partial}{\partial y}G(X(y,\epsilon))\right]=
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left[F(X(y,\epsilon))\frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon}G(X(y,\epsilon))\right]$$
as
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon}\left(F(X)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}G(X)\right)=f(X)\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(X)\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}(X)+F(X)\frac{\partial^2G}{\partial\epsilon\partial y}(X)$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(F(X)\frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon}G(X)\right)=\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(X)f(X)\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}(X)+F(X)\frac{\partial^2G}{\partial y\partial\epsilon}(X)$$
From last equations we deduce by recurrence that for every integer $n\geq 1$ and for any analytic function $g$ such that $g(0)=0$ we have
$$\frac{\partial^n g}{\partial\epsilon^n}(X(y,\epsilon))=
\frac{\partial^{n-1}}{\partial y^{n-1}}\left[f(X(y,\epsilon))^n\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(X(y,\epsilon))\right]$$
Consequently, by Taylor's formula we have:
$$g(X(y,\epsilon))=
g(X(y,0))+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\epsilon^n}{n!}\frac{\partial^{n-1}}{\partial y^{n-1}}\left[f(X(y,0))^n\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(X(y,0))\right]$$

I am struggling to understand how $\frac{\partial^n g}{\partial\epsilon^n}(X(y,\epsilon))=
\frac{\partial^{n-1}}{\partial y^{n-1}}\left[f(X(y,\epsilon))^n\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(X(y,\epsilon))\right]$. In particular, I have tried to verify the formula for $n=2$, but I find that, setting $g=G$ and $f=F$
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \epsilon^2}(g(X(y,\epsilon)))=
\frac{\partial}{\partial\epsilon}\left(\frac{\partial g(X(y,\epsilon))}{\partial\epsilon}\right)=
\frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon}\left(f(X(y,\epsilon))\frac{\partial g(X(y,\epsilon))}{\partial y}\right)
=
\frac{\partial f(X(y,\epsilon))}{\partial \epsilon}\frac{\partial g(X(y,\epsilon))}{\partial y}+
f(X(y,\epsilon)\frac{\partial^2 g(X(y,\epsilon))}{\partial \epsilon\partial y}
=
f(X(y,\epsilon))\frac{\partial f(X(y,\epsilon))}{\partial y}\frac{\partial g(X(y,\epsilon))}{\partial y}+
f^2(X(y,\epsilon))\frac{\partial^2 g(X(y,\epsilon))}{\partial^2 y}
$$
whereas if I develop
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left[f(X(y,\epsilon))^2\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(X(y,\epsilon))\right]=
2f(X(y,\epsilon)) \frac{\partial f(X(y,\epsilon))}{\partial y}\frac{\partial g(X(y,\epsilon))}{\partial y}+f^2(X(y,\epsilon))\frac{\partial^2 g(X(y,\epsilon))}{\partial^2 y}{\partial y}
$$ which is not the same because the factor $2$. I must be doing some dumb error but I cannot see where.
On the other hand, if I apply the formula $$\frac{\partial}{\partial\epsilon}\left[F(X(y,\epsilon))\frac{\partial}{\partial y}G(X(y,\epsilon))\right]=
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left[F(X(y,\epsilon))\frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon}G(X(y,\epsilon))\right]$$ to $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon}\left(f(X(y,\epsilon))\frac{\partial g(X(y,\epsilon))}{\partial y}\right)$$ I get $$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left[f(X(y,\epsilon))^2\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(X(y,\epsilon))\right]$$ as desired.
What is the difference?
How does it work for $n \geq 2$?
thanks

I will attempt to answer, to my own question. Amendments and improvements are welcome.
I believe the mistake I was doing in the calculation was thinking the below was a chain of equalities:
$$\frac{\partial^2g(X(\epsilon,y))}{\partial\epsilon\partial y}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial g(X(\epsilon,y))}{\partial \epsilon}\right)\neq \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(f(X(\epsilon,y))\frac{\partial g(X(\epsilon,y))}{\partial y}\right)$$
this is because, if we call $\frac{\partial g()}{\partial \epsilon}=G()$ we have that $\frac{\partial g(X(\epsilon,y))}{\partial \epsilon}\neq G(X(\epsilon,y))$ but rather $\frac{\partial g(X(\epsilon,y))}{\partial \epsilon}= G(X(\epsilon,y))\frac{\partial X(\epsilon,y)}{\partial \epsilon}$ so that the following holds:
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \epsilon^2}(g(X(y,\epsilon)))=
\frac{\partial}{\partial\epsilon}\left(\frac{\partial g(X(y,\epsilon))}{\partial\epsilon}\right)=\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon}\left(f(X(y,\epsilon))\frac{\partial g(X(y,\epsilon))}{\partial y}\right)
=
\frac{\partial f(X(y,\epsilon))}{\partial \epsilon}\frac{\partial g(X(y,\epsilon))}{\partial y}+
f(X(y,\epsilon)\frac{\partial^2 g(X(y,\epsilon))}{\partial \epsilon\partial y}
=\\
f(X(y,\epsilon))\frac{\partial f(X(y,\epsilon))}{\partial y}\frac{\partial g(X(y,\epsilon))}{\partial y}+
f(X(y,\epsilon))\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial g(X(y,\epsilon))}{\partial \epsilon}\right)
=
f(X(y,\epsilon))\frac{\partial f(X(y,\epsilon))}{\partial y}\frac{\partial g(X(y,\epsilon))}{\partial y}+
f(X(y,\epsilon))\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial g(X(y,\epsilon))}{\partial y}f(X(y,\epsilon))\right)
=
2f(X(y,\epsilon)) \frac{\partial f(X(y,\epsilon))}{\partial y}\frac{\partial g(X(y,\epsilon))}{\partial y}+f^2(X(y,\epsilon))\frac{\partial^2 g(X(y,\epsilon))}{\partial^2 y}
=
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left[f(X(y,\epsilon))^2\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(X(y,\epsilon))\right]
$$
as desired.
As for the general $n$ case, I think we can proceed as follows
Suppose we have the relation (which we just proved, for $n=2$):
$$
\frac{\partial^n g(X)}{\partial \epsilon^n}=\frac{\partial^{n-1}}{\partial y^{n-1}}\left[f(X)^n\frac{\partial g(X)}{\partial y}\right]
$$
we have that
$$
\frac{\partial^{n+1} g(X)}{\partial \epsilon^{n+1}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon}\frac{\partial^{n-1}}{\partial y^{n-1}}\left[f(X)^n\frac{\partial g(X)}{\partial y}\right]=
\frac{\partial^{n-1}}{\partial y^{n-1}}\frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon}\left[f(X)^n\frac{\partial g(X)}{\partial y}\right]=
\frac{\partial^{n-1}}{\partial y^{n-1}}\left[nf(X)^{n-1}\frac{\partial f(X)}{\partial \epsilon}\frac{\partial g(X)}{\partial y}+f(X)^n\frac{\partial^2 g(X)}{\partial y\partial \epsilon}\right]
=
\frac{\partial^{n-1}}{\partial y^{n-1}}\left[
nf(X)^n\frac{\partial f(X)}{\partial y}\frac{\partial g(X)}{\partial y}+f(X)^{n+1}\frac{\partial^2 g(X)}{\partial y}+f(X)^n\frac{\partial g(X)}{\partial y}\frac{\partial f(X)}{\partial y}
\right]
=
\frac{\partial^{n-1}}{\partial y^{n-1}}\left[
(n+1)f(X)^n\frac{\partial f(X)}{\partial y}\frac{\partial g(X)}{\partial y}+f(X)^{n+1}\frac{\partial^2 g(X)}{\partial y}
\right]
=
\frac{\partial^{n}}{\partial y^{n}}\left[f(X)^{n+1}\frac{\partial g(X)}{\partial y}\right]
$$
